# Possible to update data on Parse server without calling save?

Tags: c#, parse-platform

Is there anyway I can update the data on Parse server without calling Save/SaveAsync() ?

Meaning I'm looking for something which I can instantly modify the data.

For example:

```
ParseUser.CurrentUser["name"] = "New Name"; 
// this straight away update the "name" field on Parse server even I haven't call SaveAsync().
```

I'm asking the question like this is because I want to avoid network latency issues. I'm so worry that the save process might fail in the middle which will cause a lot of troubles to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a work around with cloud functions.
Take a look there.
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide?language=Windows#functions-calling

Comment: Cloud Function doesn't help because even I modify the data through cloud function I still require to call SaveAsync then the data only able to sync to the actual server.

Comment: So actually you want to save without saving. That's sounds like a oxymoron that are used in poems. But isn't there a built in mechanism that saves your data local and if there is a connection synchronise them?

Comment: you mean local datastore in parse?

Comment: Yes. Look what @JayDev wrote.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that you are looking at using a local datastore. Your problem is that Parse have implemented the local datastore and saveEventually method for other SDKs such as Android, but are yet to create similar functionality for the .NET SDK. So currently I know no way that you can do this in .NET

Comment: You could always post a question on the Parse forum, and see if they are planning on porting the local datastore over to .NET any time soon?

Comment: There is no Parse forum now.... any question we have is either post on  stackoverflow or google group.... their forum is only treated as an archive for past questions.